# Construct bivariate symmetric (polynomial) Hilbert-Schmidt two-qubit volume functions over the unit square with certain properties

Tags: differential-geometry, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, probability, volume

Construct bivariate symmetric polynomials (two-qubit  volume functions) f(r,R) = f(R,r) >= 0 over [0,1]^2, with f(1,R) = f(r,1)=0,  such that the univariate marginal (integrating over r or R) distributions are both proportional to

(1-u^2)^4, where u is either r or R

and the "diagonal" f(r,r) = f(R,R) is proportional to

(1-u)^5.

(R and r correspond to the radii of the pair of two-level mixed states in the Bloch sphere, obtained by tracing over a four-level [two-qubit] system.)

Also, the same form of (now, strictly Hilbert-Schmidt) problem with marginals

(1-u^2)^6

and diagonal

(1-u)^9 (1+8 u).

And a third (random induced measure) case requiring the marginals

(1-u^2)^8

and diagonal

(1-u)^(11) ((1+u (11+40 u)).

These problems have a quantum-information-theoretic relevance pertaining to two-qubit separability probability calculations, following the work of Milz and Strunz 
(J. Phys. A 48 [2015] 035306, also http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08739). The functions requested above pertain to total volume (Hilbert-Schmidt and random induced measure) calculations, while I have three companion problems pertaining to separable volume calculations. Of course, the ratios of such functions would yield separability probability results.

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1402942/11127

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use $x$ and $y$ in place of $r$ and $R$, as you did in the cross-post on Math Stack Exchange, just for notational sanity.  And I will answer only the first of these, but I will show the method.

So the task is to find some $f(x,y)$ which such that:
$$
\forall \{x,y\}: f(y,x)=f(x,y)\\
\int_{y=0}^1 f(x,y)dy = (1-x^2)^4 = 1-4x^2+6x^4-4x^6+x^8 \\
\int_{x=0}^1 f(x,y)dx = (1-y^2)^4 = 1-4y^2+6y^4-4y^6+y^8 \\
f(x,x) = (1-x)^5
$$
(Actually, the second of those marginal integral conditions is redundant since it is implied by the first two conditions.)

The first observation is that the desired probability distribution function need not be unique.  We will attempt to find a solution as a polynomial function, of the form
$$
f(x,y) = k(x,y) + h(x,y) 
$$
where $h(x,x)$ is identically zero.  Note that a polynomial which is identically zero when $x=y$ and is symmetric in $x$ and $y$  must be the sum of terms of the form $(x^p-y^p)^{2s}$.

Since $h(x,x)$ is identically zero, $k(x,y)$ alone must satisfy 
$$k(x,x) = (1-x)^5 $$ and therefore $k(x,y)$ must be a symmetric polynomial of degree at least $5$.  It will also need to have at least six terms, so that we have freedom to adjust six coefficients to match the six coefficients in $(1-x)^5$.

A starting point will be to use only terms of the forms $(x+y)^n$ and $(x^n+y^n)$:
$$k(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^6 k_n(x+y)^n +\sum_{n=2}^6 \bar{k}_n(x^n+y^n)$$
We could start from only the $k_n$ terms, or limit the degree to $5$ instead of $6$,  but we would find that the work in ensuring the proper marginal distributions is simpler if we allow this freedom in $k(x,y)$.
Applying the constraints that $k(x,x) = (1-x)^5$ we find several relations amongst the $k_n$ and $\bar{k}_n$, leading to
$$k(x,y)= k_6(x+y)^6 - 32k_6(x^6+y^6) +k_5(x+y)^5 - \frac{1+32 k_5}{2} (x^5+y^5)+ k_4(x+y)^4 + \frac{5-16 k_4}{2} (x^4+y^4) + 
k_3(x+y)^3 - (5 + 4k_3 )(x^3+y^3)+k_2(x+y)^32+(5 - 2k_2 )(x^2+y^2)-\frac{5}{5}(x+y)+1
$$
It is easy to verify that $k(x,x) = (1-x)^5$; if (like me) you used to do supergravity Lagrangian calculations by hand, you don't need a symbolic algebra program like Mathematica, but it sure helps.

Now we attack $h(x,y)$, which will need to have terms of degree $8$, and we will find that an adequate form has only three free parameters:
$$
h(x,y) = \alpha(x^2-y^2)^4 + (1-\alpha)(x^4-y^4)^2+\gamma(\alpha(x^2-y^2)^2
$$
Note that we are constrained (by the symmetry requirement) to raise any antisymmetric terms in $x$ and $y$ to even powers; this is the reason why extra freedom in $k(x,y)$ turns out to be valuable.

Now when we do the $y$ integration, we get 
$$
\int_0^1 (h(x,y)+k(x,y))dy = x^8 - (31k_6 + \frac43\alpha) x^6 + (3k_6-15k_5-\frac12)x^5 + \cdots
$$
You can see that it is easy to determine  $k_6$ in terms of$\alpha$ by demanding that the coefficient of $x^6$ is $-4$, and then $k_5$ in terms of $\alpha$  by demanding that the coefficient of $x^5$ is zero. At this point you have
$$
\int_0^1 (h(x,y)+k(x,y))dy = x^8 -4x^6 + \left( \frac{5071}{1860}-7k_4+\frac{634}{465}\alpha+\gamma\right)x^4 + \cdots
$$
(and this is where I left the comfort of a big art pad, for the superior comfort of Mathematica).

The expression for the integral has five remaining coefficients to adjust, and there are five remaining parameters to twiddle.  You can solve for those parameters, getting the solution
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{4375}{256}(x^2-y^2)^4 -\frac{4119}{256}(x^4-y^4)^2 
+ \frac{6136937}{49600}(x^2-y^2)^2 \\
+ \frac{3607}{186}(x^6+y^6)-\frac{3607}{5952}(x+y)^6 
\\+\frac{1223}{620}(x^5+y^5) - \frac{1533}{9920}(x+y)^5
\\ + \frac{42781757}{2083200}(x+y)^4 
-\frac{42130757}{260400}(x^4+y^4)\\
+\frac{5646847}{520800}(x+y)^3 - \frac{6297847}{130200}(x^3+y^3) \\
+\frac{12576953}{208320}(x^2+y^2) - \frac{11715353}{416640}(x+y)^2
\\ -\frac52(x+y)+1
$$

Now that the methodology is clear, the other two problems should be straightforward, if incredibly tedious.

Comment: I referenced  (in the abstract and end) this interesting, diligent piece of analysis by Mark Fischler in my posting https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06459.pdf which is in press at the Intl. J. Quantum Information. I hadn't seen the "Unfortunately,..." caveat at the crossposted math.stack. exchange (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402942/construct-bivariate-symmetric-polynomial-nonnegative-functions-distributions) at the time. Still an impressive endeavor.